# Need help sorting folders according to folder names (Sorting Music)

Tags: shell, sorting, command-line-interface, rename, directory-structure

I need to bulk move folders to a parent folder according to the child's folders name. It's a bit too abstract to explain so here is an example. (It's for sorting music)

```
AC DC - Backtracks [3 CD Deluxe Edition] (2009)
AC DC - Stiff Upper Lip (2000) 
AC_DC - Back In Black
AC_DC - High Voltage
AC_DC - Highway to Hell
```

A parent folder should be created if not already existent, in this case "AC DC" and "AC_DC". The first "-" in each row is the limiter for the parent folder name (there can be more than 1 "-", so it should only be the first). After parent folder creation or detection, the original folder should be moved to the parent folder.

I failed to do this by automation with the software advanced renamer. I am open for Linux bash solutions as well as Windows CLI or other.

Comment: Make a small test directory and files, then in a linux environment, experiment like `echo mv "$file" "${file%%-*}/$file" When you have one that looks like it will work, remove the `echo` and see if the command succeeds. You'll need to include real attempt at code so your future Qs don't get voted-closed for lack of detail. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Hmm all those spaces and `()` chars are going to make this more difficult. Post a new Q after you have some code an research to demonstrate. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. Sorry i did not provide an attempt in my initial post. Unfortunately i was not able to get your solution to work. But i was successful with a tool i found just recently: [Brename](https://github.com/shenwei356/brename). I used it with this command: `brename -D -p '^(.*?) - ' -r '$1/'`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this done with this [tool](https://github.com/shenwei356/brename)
Here is the `brename -D -p '^(.*?) - ' -r '$1/'` make sure to use "-d" for testing!

Comment: Glad you got a solution. Will be happy to upvote your answer if you include some of the documentation of the`brename` in your answer. Use the `>` tool on the Edit menu to get correct formatting for documentation. Just include the description of what the tool is for (usually in the first paragraph). Good luck.